# Extraño error con DomPDF

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, estoy intentando crear un fichero PDF.
Esta es la vista que quiero crear:

@include('layouts.estilo')

```
<?php
    $categoria=$articulo->categoria();
?>
<h2 class="text-center card-title">{{$articulo->titulo}}</h2>
<hr>
<center>
    @if($categoria=="columna")
        <h4><img class="card-img-top" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius:150px;" src="{{url($articulo->user->ruta())}}"/> {{$articulo->user->nombre()}}</h4>
        <br>
    @else
        <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Esta noticia de {{$articulo->tipo->nombre}} la escribio {{$articulo->user->nombre()}}</span><br>
    @endif
    <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Esta {{$categoria}} ha sido publicada el {{$articulo->creado()}}</span>
    @if($articulo->created_at<$articulo->updated_at)
        <br><span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Fue actualizada por última vez el {{$articulo->cambiado()}}</span>
    @endif
</center>
<hr>
<img class="card-img-top" style="width: auto; height: 300px;" src="{{url($articulo->foto->ruta())}}"/>
<hr>
<h3 style="white-space: pre-line;">{{$articulo->texto}}</h3>
```

Pero me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto correspondiente al `style="white-space: pre-line;"` se sale en su última linea. ¿Cómo impido eso?
Provisionalmente lo he solucionado provocando un salto de línea con `."\n"`, pero claramente esto es una chapuza.

Comment: Esa línea es un `<h3>`. Ten cuidado de que no tenga algún estilo que entre en conflicto con lo que tú quieres. Prueba a cambiarla a `<p>` y si divide las líneas bien investiga a partir de ahí.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas Pues con la etiqueta <p> el error sigue.

Comment: Utiliza la consola para ver todos los estilos. Desatívalos todos y ve activando uno a uno.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución, pero es chapuza.

```
@include('layouts.estilo')

<?php
    $categoria=$articulo->categoria();
    $texto=$articulo->texto."\n";
?>
<h2 class="text-center card-title">{{$articulo->titulo}}</h2>
<hr>
<center>
    @if($categoria=="columna")
        <h4><img class="card-img-top" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius:150px;" src="{{url($articulo->user->ruta())}}"/> {{$articulo->user->nombre()}}</h4>
        <br>
    @else
        <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Esta noticia de {{$articulo->tipo->nombre}} la escribio {{$articulo->user->nombre()}}</span><br>
    @endif
    <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Esta {{$categoria}} ha sido publicada el {{$articulo->creado()}}</span>
    @if($articulo->created_at<$articulo->updated_at)
        <br><span class="badge badge-cat badge-info" style="white-space: pre-line;">Fue actualizada por última vez el {{$articulo->cambiado()}}</span>
    @endif
</center>
<hr>
<img class="card-img-top" style="width: auto; height: 300px;" src="{{url($articulo->foto->ruta())}}"/>
<hr>
<h3 style="white-space: pre-line;">{{$texto}}</h3>
```

Si se pone un salto de línea, ya no me da el error.